# Push notification retrieved in iOS but not in Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am facing this strange issue in my application. I am trying to integrate push notification in my application using firebase. I have included Firebase SDK in the project using the downloaded SDK(not using pod). I have included the following frameworks from the downloaded zip file in the application:

[image]

In AppDelegate

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}

// This is called and the access token is received.
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    var token = ""
    for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {
        token = token + String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [deviceToken[i]])
    }
    print(token)
    Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .sandbox)
}

// This is not getting called
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "ios_topic")
}
```

The access token I get in `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is valid and I successfully sent push to the device using that. But the `didRefreshRegistrationToken` of FireBase is not getting called. I have added `-ObjC` in linkerflags and `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` as `NO` in `info.plist`. I have added the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file in the project root, and the project is configured correctly in FireBase console.

What is the possible issue here and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

That was the silliest of mistakes while following the tutorials. Just needed to set the delegate of `Messaging.messaging()` as `AppDelegate`. Add the following code right under `FirebaseApp.configure()` and the issue is solved.

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
```